# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int' in Python, cannot figure solution

Tags: python

I tried understanding this error from other examples but I couldn't figure it out. Code returns Error in title.

```
def truckloads_of_asphalt(miles, lanes, asphalt_depth):
    total_feet = ((miles*5280) * (lanes * 12)) * (asphalt_depth/12)
    total_asphalt_truck = math.ceil((((total_feet * 145)/2000))/5)
    return total_asphalt_truck

asphalt_cost = (truckloads_of_asphalt * 5 * 145)
print('Cost of asphalt : ', (asphalt_cost))
```

The issue is basically that I am trying to print the value of asphalt_cost, which is the result of: `(truckloads_of_asphalt * 5 * 145)` but I am getting this error.

Comment: `truckloads_of_asphalt() * 5 * 145`, please call the function.

Comment: Of course you have proper indentation in the original code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called your `function` and assigned the return value to a `variable` it other than that you were alright

```
import math

def truckloads_of_asphalt(miles, lanes, asphalt_depth):
    total_feet = ((miles*5280) * (lanes * 12)) * (asphalt_depth/12)
    total_asphalt_truck = math.ceil((((total_feet * 145)/2000))/5)
    return total_asphalt_truck

vash  = truckloads_of_asphalt(60, 2, 4)
asphalt_cost = (vash * 5 * 145)
print('Cost of asphalt : ', (asphalt_cost))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 trucks.py
> Cost of asphalt :  26643025
> ```

Worthwhile to get familiar with `f-strings`:

```
print(f"Cost of asphalt: {asphalt_cost}")
```

Comment: This is too advanced for my assignment. I can only use material I have learned from class unforunately.

Comment: Which is too advanced, you don't have to use the `f-string` that was just a bonus

Answer (score 0):

```
def truckloads_of_asphalt(miles, lanes, asphalt_depth):
    total_feet = ((miles*5280) * (lanes * 12)) * (asphalt_depth/12)
    total_asphalt_truck = math.ceil((((total_feet * 145)/2000))/5)
    return total_asphalt_truck

asphalt_cost = (truckloads_of_asphalt(miles, lanes, asphalt_depth) * 5 * 145) 
print('Cost of asphalt : ', (asphalt_cost))
```

You have not called the function truckloads_of_asphalt.